# Limit Problem - No clue where to start

Tags: limits, infinity

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x^{2011}+2010^x}{-x^{2010}+2011^x}$$

I'm not sure where to even start with this one. One idea I had was that perhaps it could be "split" up as:

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x^{2011}}{-x^{2010}+2011^x} + \lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{2010^x}{-x^{2010}+2011^x}$$

But solving this requires knowledge of the answer to the following question: What are the dominant terms? is $\infty^c > c^\infty$? It might even be an indeterminate form to which L'hopital's rule can be applied, but even if it was I'm not sure how to take the derivative of something to the power of x. D:

Comment: HINT: For very large $x$ the exponentials dominate, and the fraction is approximately $\left(\frac{2010}{2011}\right)^x$. (This is not a rigorous evaluation, but it at least gets you looking in the right direction.)

Comment: When you put it like that, I can easily see it's a fraction < 0 to the power of infinity, so the result approaches 0. Could you please show the full "formal" steps as would be required in an exam?

Comment: @AndréNicolas is there such a trick? I would be interested in that!

Comment: @AndréNicolas. You have some typos 2011 instead of 2001 twice.

Comment: Thank you. I will delete to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach: divide the top and bottom by $2011^x$ to get
$$
\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x^{2011}+2010^x}{-x^{2010}+2011^x} 
= 
\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\frac{x^{2011}}{2011^x}+\left(\frac{2010}{2011}\right)^x}{-\frac{x^{2010}}{2011^x} + 1}
$$
Where can you go from there?

Also, for the record: for any positive number $a$, we have
$$
\frac{d}{dx}a^x = \frac{d}{dx}e^{ln(a)\,x} = \ln(a)e^{\ln(a)\,x} = \ln(a) \,a^x
$$

---

In general: if you have to evaluate a limit of the form $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x^n}{a^x}$ for positive number $a$ and integer $n$, you could note that
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x^n}{a^x} = \left(\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x}{a^{x/n}}\right)^n = \left(\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x}{e^{\frac{\ln(a)}{n}x}}\right)^n
$$
From there, you could use L'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: I can't see how this can help if the OP isn't sure what's the dominant term: the polynomial or the exponential.

Comment: I suppose that's a fair point. I think I should call it a night soon.

Answer (score 3):

We could begin by evaluating, for $\;x>0\;$

$$x^{2010}<2011^x\iff2010\log x<x\log2011$$

and the second inequality is clear for $
\;x\;$ big enough, so exponential rules over polynomial, and thus

$$\frac{x^{2010}}{-x^{2010}+2011^x}\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}0\\{}$$

$$\frac{2010^x}{-x^{2010}+2011^x}\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}0$$

Comment: This implies the answer is 1, according to Wolfram Alpha it's 0 D:

Comment: I might be wrong, of course, but I so do not care what WA says. Just in the last 4-5 months it has given several pretty wrong and/or incomplete answers to quests of members here. I wouldn't rely blindly on what a program says...

Comment: And I can see where the confusion is: I wrote $\;2011\;$ instead of $\;2010\;$ in the numerator. It never minds, the principle still is valid, of course.

Answer (score 0):

As said by Brian M. Scott, for large values of x, the exponentials dominate and the problem reduces to the limit of (2010 / 2011)^x when x goes to infinity. So, the result is zero (as confirmed by Wolfram Alpha).